# MySQL Sleep time query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How to increase the time for the queries to auto kill themselves. What exactly should I be doing to eliminate this repeated error.

I am using PrestaShop and I have been facing these queries which are crowding my server as reported by my server assistant.

> Thu Jun 18 09:56:15 +0000 2015 [info] killed_thread_id:11508142 user:pres102 host:localhost db:pres102 command:Sleep time:21 query:

These are repeatedly being displayed in the list of killed queries.
In which file do I make the changes for these queries to be resolved correctly?
Also what other changes in which file I should make to kill other queries. I do not know the file name in PrestaShop where such queries and their changes should be made. Please help.

Comment: your problem is not clear, are u facing issue related with so many queries are showing in sleep mode if you are checking processlist or else.

Comment: My page is taking upto 5 second to load ....every page in my website first takes a hault for 5-6 seconds and then starts downloading . Hence the server- Hostgator was called who said these MySQL queries are causing the problem.

Comment: which sql queries as per you can create issue, first of all you can execute these queries manually and check their time...if these queries are taking more time then expected then can check possibility of any optimization or it will be clear that issue is due to queries or somewhere else.

Comment: How do I check these queries , not very good at coding.I have shared server so I can't see all the running queries. What is the best alternative ?

Comment: 1. If slow logs are enable and these are slow queries then you can check in slowlogs, 2. You can print all running queries (near about time at which time this problem arise) to a temp file and then monitor them. 3. May be your query is not slow but consuming server resources at the time of bulk execution due to table scan, so you you can on general_log for some time and monitor queries here...there can be various ways but you can know better what suits to you.

Comment: I don't have any option such as slow logs enabled in my control panel . However there is something  called PHPMyAdmin . I know how to enable debug mode kn Prestashop but yet don't know how to view the running MySQL queries on my website.